# how to access an object from other objects

Tags: python, object, reference

I'm solving some excerices and despite spending quite some time on this question, I was not able to find the answer, so here's my problem:

I have 2 classes, let's call them Room and Vacuum. The Room contains dirty tiles, and the Vacuum will clean it. The instance of the room is passed as an argument into the vacuum instances.

The question is: how can I initialize a "pointer" to the room instance? My goal is to be able to have multiple vacuum objects "cleaning" the same room at the same time. As far as I can tell if I use
self.room = room
in the vacuum __init __ , this will create a new object inside each instance of the vacuum rather than linking the existing room to all vacuums.

Before it is suggested: I cannot change the class arguments as these are fixed as a requirement.

Edit:
Sample code:

```py
class Room(object):
    """
    A Room represents a rectangular region containing clean or dirty
    tiles.

    A room has a width and a height and contains (width * height) tiles. At any
    particular time, each of these tiles is either clean or dirty.
    """
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        """
        Initializes a room with the specified width and height.

        Initially, no tiles in the room have been cleaned.

        width: an integer > 0
        height: an integer > 0
        """
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.clean_tiles = []
        self.dirty_tiles = []
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                self.dirty_tiles.append((i,j))
...
    def cleanTileAtPosition(self, pos):
        """
        Mark the tile under the position POS as cleaned.

        Assumes that POS represents a valid position inside this room.

        pos: a Position
        """
        tile = (int(pos.getX()), int(pos.getY()))
        if tile in self.dirty_tiles:
            self.dirty_tiles.remove(tile)
            self.clean_tiles.append(tile)


class Vacuum(object):
    """
    Represents a robot cleaning a particular room.

    At all times the robot has a particular position and direction in the room.
    The robot also has a fixed speed.

    Subclasses of Robot should provide movement strategies by implementing
    updatePositionAndClean(), which simulates a single time-step.
    """
    def __init__(self, room, speed):
        """
        Initializes a Robot with the given speed in the specified room. The
        robot initially has a random direction and a random position in the
        room. The robot cleans the tile it is on.

        room:  a RectangularRoom object.
        speed: a float (speed > 0)
        """
        self.room = room
        self.speed = speed
        self.direction = random.randint(0, 360)
        self.pos = Position(random.uniform(0, self.room.width), random.uniform(0,room.height))
        self.room.cleanTileAtPosition(self.pos)


...

and the subclass of Vacuum, that will actually be used to create instances:

class StandardVacuum(Vacuum):
    """
    A StandardVacuum is a Vacuum with the standard movement strategy.

    At each time-step, a StandardRobot attempts to move in its current
    direction; when it would hit a wall, it *instead* chooses a new direction
    randomly.
    """
    def updatePositionAndClean(self):
        """
        Simulate the passage of a single time-step.

        Move the robot to a new position and mark the tile it is on as having
        been cleaned.
        """
        
        # print("current pos: ", self.pos)
        
        new_pos = self.pos.getNewPosition(self.direction, self.speed)
        
        while self.room.isPositionInRoom(new_pos) == False:
            self.setRobotDirection(random.randint(0, 360))
            # print("direction: ", self.direction)
            new_pos = self.pos.getNewPosition(self.direction, self.speed)
            # print("new pos is:", new_pos)
        
        self.setRobotPosition(new_pos)
        self.room.cleanTileAtPosition(self.pos)
```

Comment: Edit and Add some sample code so that it is easier to understand. Also show what you've done so far.

Comment: @ShoryaSharma I've updated the post with the code